# Error unzipping file through ksh, unzip works through bash

Tags: bash, ksh, zip

I have an auto-generated zipfile `foo.zip` on a Red Hat server that needs to be extracted to a particular location `/bar`. This is done through an install script using ksh. When the script executes `unzip foo.zip -d /bar`, the following error is logged:

```
caution: zipfile comment truncated
missing 3232546375 bytes in zipfile
attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
```

Executing the same command in bash extracts the zipfile without errors.

Running `unzip -t foo.zip` gives me zero errors.

What can be causing this?

Comment: what user does the ksh script run as? and have you used full paths in the script to both the zip file and the destination path? does running 
"which unzip" from the script provide the same result running it from the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

For those who may stumble upon a similar problem: the zip file had been processed by Maven, which attempted to use filtering. As per the Maven documentation, this filtering can corrupt binary files. After excluding zip files from Maven's filtering, unzipping worked fine.